# ActionListener Event in Java

Tags: java, swing

Ok, i started learning java, and this is a code from internet that doesn't work on my pc

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class form2 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Create Frame 1
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame 1");
        frame.setSize(333,333);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        // Create button
        JButton button = new JButton("Press me!");

        // Add things
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Add the action listener to that button
        button.addActionListener(new action());

        static class action implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                // Create Frame 2
                JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Frame 2");
                frame2.setSize(200,200);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JLabel label = new JLabel("Clicked!");
                JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

                // First add to frame2 the panel just create
                frame2.add(panel2);

                // Add to panel the label
                panel2.add(label);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And it give me an error about **action** and i don't understand why.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
action cannot be resolved to a type
Illegal modifier for the local class action; only abstract or final is permitted

at form2.main(form2.java:26)
```

What is my problem?? On that guy's computer works

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEXxaPQ_fQo&feature=channel_video_title

Can anyone help me??

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring a static class inside of a method which you shouldn't do. So take it out of the method, or better, make it an anonymous inner class:

```
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Create Frame 2
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Frame 2");
        frame2.setSize(200, 200);
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Clicked!");
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        // First add to frame2 the panel just create
        frame2.add(panel2);

        // Add to panel the label
        panel2.add(label);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
     }
  });
```

What does this question have to do with java-ee by the way??

Comment: oh, i'm sorry for that ... btw, so i must put it someware? i don't understand ...

Comment: thanks, i figure out, but i believe it's more ordered to put it outside, like i used to work with C++ C# ...

Comment: thanks, but i have a little question, why i have to put frame2.setVisible(true); at the end of frame2 to see the text??? In that guy video he put it above a lot, at my computer it has to be the last line ...

Comment: You should render the window only after all components have been added.

Answer (score 2):

Static classes cannot be defined inside a method. Move the class definition `static class .... { }` outside of your main method. Also, it is good practice to start classes with an uppercase character (e.g `AddPanelAction`).

Comment: Classes in Java can be defined inside a method if they are non-static.

Comment: thanks, but i have a little question, why i have to put frame2.setVisible(true); at the end of frame2 to see the text??? In that guy video he put it above a lot, at my computer it has to be the last line ...

Answer (score 2):

You declare a class inside a method, in this case `main`, however, it should be outside of it, like the guy in the video says.

Hope that helps!

Comment: ok, thanks, it was my mistake, i feel sorry i diden't saw it, i have to work with classes more in the future

Comment: thanks, but i have a little question, why i have to put frame2.setVisible(true); at the end of frame2 to see the text??? In that guy video he put it above a lot, at my computer it has to be the last line ...

Answer (score 1):

Static classes can not be defined inside a method. Move that class outside the `main` method or declare your class non-static within the `main` method itself, if you need . A static class always requires one outer non-static class.

Comment: thanks, but i have a little question, why i have to put frame2.setVisible(true); at the end of frame2 to see the text??? In that guy video he put it above a lot, at my computer it has to be the last line ...

Comment: Then where do you want to place it? It needs to be there else you might render without adding all of the components and might run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

The actionlistener class must be declared outside of the main method like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Create Frame 1
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame 1");
        frame.setSize(333,333);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        // Create button
        JButton button = new JButton("Press me!");

        // Add things
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Add the action listener to that button
        button.addActionListener(new action());

    }

    public static class action implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Create Frame 2
                JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Frame 2");
                frame2.setSize(200,200);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JLabel label = new JLabel("Clicked!");
                JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

                // First add to frame2 the panel just create
                frame2.add(panel2);

                // Add to panel the label
                panel2.add(label);
        }

    }

}
```

Or you can declare the actionlistener by using an anonymous inner class like this:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Do things here
            }

        });
```

Comment: thanks, but i have a little question, why i have to put frame2.setVisible(true); at the end of frame2 to see the text??? In that guy video he put it above a lot, at my computer it has to be the last line ...

Answer (score 1):

A day late and dollar short.... but I'll still add it.

Most of the Java actionListener examples on the web are too darn complex.  To understand it, you just really need a form, button, and the actionListener.  In the example below, the form server as the listener through the addition of 'implements ActionListener'.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Sample extends Applet implements ActionListener {
    Button button;

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        button = new Button("Test");
        add("Center", button);

        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // your code to do what you want when the button was clicked goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Having your GUI class implement its own listener works for simple examples and toy programs but doesn't scale well at all and should not be used in "real-world" programs. It is not something I would recommend.

Comment: I would concur, but note that the OP stated in his first sentence that 'he was just learning Java".  Didn't want to throw him to the lions on first time out.